# Suppress Figure Number in Caption While Show Figure Number When Referencing It

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing

I encountered a strange problem when referencing to figure in text.  The link to the figure is established as is evidenced in the red box in the compiled PDF.  But it is the question mark instead of figure number that is shown up in the red box.  Could somebody help me troubleshoot this?

The PDF snapshot is here:
[image]

The code is below (I used \usepackage{caption} to suppress the figure number in the caption, I swap the order of \caption and \label and it does not help):

```
\begin{description}
    \item[ideal market theorem:] the ideal market picture consists of an uptrend, top, downtrend, and bottom (figure~\ref{fig:DowIdealMarketPicture}), interspersed with retracements and consolidations, the purpose of the ideal market picture is to provide a generalized model of the stock market's price behavior over time, it presumes that prices \underline{oscillate} over long periods based on the accumulated \underline{emotion} of investors as well as the facts of the \underline{business cycle}
        \begin{figure}[hbt]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.54]{Figure/DowIdealMarketPicture}
            \caption*{figure 2.1 the Dow theory ideal market picture}
            \label{fig:DowIdealMarketPicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{description}
```

The the log file contains the following warning message:

> Package caption Warning: \label without proper reference on input line 150.
> See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Comment: you have used `\caption*` so there is no number and so nothing to `\label`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there any way to suppress figure number in caption and at the same time show figure number in reference?

Comment: why can you not use `\caption` as normal, then let latex generate `Figure 2.1` then `Figure~\ref{fig:DowIdealMarketPicture}` can access the `Figure 2.1` text as normal.

Comment: Why do you want to write `figure 2.1 ` "by hand"?

Comment: You could of course do that but you would have no automated check that the actual figure number matched the text that looks like a figure number that you added to the caption so it would be very fragile and weird

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi David, that figure 2.1 refers to the figure number in the textbook, not my PDF notes. I wish to keep the original figure number in the textbook.  That is why I have to manually "overwrite" the figure number.

Comment: so you wouldn't want `\ref` to print the unprinted "real" figure counter anyway you want it to magically find the "2.1" from the free text of the caption? hitorically for such a fixed text the answer would be as it is not auto numbered you do not need \label and \ref as you can simply write "See Figure 2.1"  as you know the number in advance, but i suppose you want a hyperlink?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes David, I want the hyperlink. As to what appears in the red box, as long as it is a legitimate figure number (either in the textbook or in my PDF notes) instead of question marks I would be satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set `\@currentlabel` manually. If you're using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as well, then an additional `\phantomsection` should provide the correct hypertarget.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setrefnumber}{\phantomsection\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[ideal market theorem:] the ideal market picture consists of an uptrend, 
    top, downtrend, and bottom (figure~\ref{fig:DowIdealMarketPicture}), interspersed 
    with retracements and consolidations, the purpose of the ideal market picture is 
    to provide a generalized model of the stock market's price behavior over time, it 
    presumes that prices \underline{oscillate} over long periods based on the 
    accumulated \underline{emotion} of investors as well as the facts of the 
    \underline{business cycle}
    
    \begin{figure}[hbt]
      \setrefnumber{2.1}%
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption*{figure 2.1 the Dow theory ideal market picture}
      \label{fig:DowIdealMarketPicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Note how `\setrefnumber{<whatever>}` is placed at the top of the `figure` environment so the `\ref`erence hyperlink jumps to the top of the figure.

Comment: Use phantom section and set number referring to it, what a terrific trick!  Many thanks Werner!

Comment: AFAIK the `caption` package offers `\phantomcaption`, so I assume that this one could be used, too.